# Create custom annotation to handle exceptions

Tags: java, exception, annotations

Is there a way to create your own annotation which will handle exceptions?

I mean for example if method throws some exception, instead of creating `try-catch` blocks I'd like to put annotation on the method - and it won't required to use `try-catch`.

For example something like this

```
public void method() {
    try {
        perform();
    } catch (WorkingException e) {
    }
}

@ExceptionCatcher(WorkingException.class)
public void method() {
    perform();
}
```

Comment: This might help....
Its previously asked on SO

[using-annotations-for-exception-handling][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389808/using-annotations-for-exception-handling

Comment: @NeerajJain What If OP wants annotations?

Comment: @NeerajJain `throws` passes the exception to calling method, what OP wants to achieve is to handle exception by annotation, and it should be possible, Mohit Gupta already provided good link

Answer (score 0):

AspectJ is perfect for this use case. This code will wrap any method annotated with @ExceptionCatcher in a try-catch, check if the thrown exception is a type that should be handled (based on the classes defined in @ExceptionCatcher), then run custom logic or re-throw.

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@interface ExceptionCatcher {
    public Class<? extends Throwable>[] exceptions() default {Exception.class};
}
```

AspectJ advice:

```
@Aspect
public class ExceptionCatchingAdvice {
    @Around("execution(@ExceptionCatcher * *.*(..)) && @annotation(ExceptionCatcher)")
    public Object handle(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, ExceptionCatcher catcher) throws Throwable {
        try {
            // execute advised code
            return pjp.proceed();
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            // check exceptions specified in annotation contain thrown exception
            if (Arrays.stream(catcher.exceptions())
                      .anyMatch(klass -> e.getClass().equals(klass))) {
                // custom logic goes here
            }
            // exception wasn't specified, rethrow
            else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```