# Custom @Annotation to report boolean at runtime

Tags: java, testng, junit4

I'm searching around to see if what I want to accomplish is possible with annotations.

Basically, we have a bunch of TestNG test cases which we're micro managing

Example:

```
@Test
public void reportingTest(){
 Assert.true(false);
}
```

The above would simply fail, but we wrap everything in an assertion try catch.

```
@Test
public void reportingTest(){
 try {
    Assert.true(false);
    Report.batch(Enum.Pass, 106);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Report.batch(Enum.Fail, 106, "Test case has failed");
    }
}
```

However, after hundreds of test-cases... having that try catch is super cumbersome.

I am trying to accomplish something like this

```
@Reporting(id=106)
@Test
  public void reportingTest(){
     Assert.true(false);
 }
```

Inside of the annotation I would have the ability to capture the failed assertion and send a log off based on my id.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the question 'it is possible' ? OR 'hey here is my idea and show me how?'

Comment: did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389808/using-annotations-for-exception-handling looks like something you could use

Comment: Thank you very much tagtraeumer! This looks interesting. 
and Zelldon, I guess a mix of both.. I don't need a full implementation example... what tagtraeumer linked is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestNG provides [listeners](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) and the one you are looking for may be the [TestListener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-listeners).

Your annotation will be available from there: `tr.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(Reporting.class)`.