# How To Throw customized Block Exception in Java

Tags: java, selenium, exception, annotations

I would like to know that how can i trow customized block exception in java.i will explain it on following example.

**@login**

```
//Below code snippet do log in functionality.
mycode goes here

String name="abc";
if name.equals("ABC")
{
  enter to system ...
}
```

**Console Out Put**

```
You have error on log in
```

**@register**

```
//Below code snippet do register functionality.

mycode goes here
```

let say in @login annotation there is a error from my code.java should  throw it like a good readable way.The exception should be like regular exception and where it generate.i mean code block in this case it is log in.If register it should say u have an error in register code block.

Also i don't declare annotation on top of method.In my case there is no such a method and everything handle the annotations. 
as a example

**Student Class**

```
class student{
@login
login related codes goes here

@View Result
view result related codes goes here

@logout
logout code goes here

}
```

As a example you can consider above class as a selenium script.in scripts we don't use any methods.i want to implement back end class(annotations) that gives and meaningful errors on happens in the related code block.(log in,view result,...)

when ever user write a new script he can reuse my annotation.

Actually this is a idea that i wanna implement.Because if i do like that it will be easy for my app users.so I would like to know that can it possible to do and if so how can i do it.If you know another way Please let me know your ideas.Thanks.

Comment: What isn't answered by http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/?

Comment: @JB Nizet yes it is but i want implement customized exception block.let say try catch block i want to implement something like similar exception handler for my login. in there i dont use try catch block but login block handle it and throw exception.Please if your not clear my question let me know.

Comment: So are you trying to do the exception handling without a try/catch block? I'm having a hard time following the question.

Comment: there's no such thing as an "exception block". You can throw an exception to signal an error, and you can catch an exception to handle the error. That's all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using annotations for exception handling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389808/using-annotations-for-exception-handling)

Comment: In Java you can only put annotations on classes, methods, variables, parameters, and packages. You cannot just put an annotation on an arbitrary block of code because the compiler will have no idea what the scope of the annotation should be. Which of those entities are you trying to annotate?

Comment: Seems like it is not possible to do with out declare annotation on top of classes,methods etc...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced I fully understand the question but if you're looking for creating a custom exception, you can do the following:

```
if name.equals("ABC") {
    // do something
} else {
    throw new CustomException("Name did not equal 'ABC'");
}
```

where the custom exception is defined as:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

    public CustomException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

And then wherever you need to handle the exception, it would look like:

```
try {
    // do something that might throw a CustomException
} catch (CustomException ce) {
    ce.printStackTrace();
    // or do something more useful to handle the exception
}
```

And if you go this route, I would call it something other than `CustomException`, call it something that is relevant to the problem the exception pertains to, for example `NameNotEqualException`.

Comment: i want something similar to this but my exceptions handle by login annotation.login annotation responsible for handling its below code block and if there is an error i want to print that "the error was in login".

Comment: What are these `@login` and `@register` annotations from? What do they do exactly?

Comment: let think i have created custom annotation login.and every time developer implementing related to login functionality stuff.he must declare @login annotation on top of  his code.like my question.and if there are error in that code system should print it like "error was on log in" with out pass actual error. Note : log in and register are still just a idea.i will edit my code then you can get an clear idea.

Comment: Log in and @register annotations  are the actually handle the exception.it is not yet implemented .that's why i asked how can i implement them to monitoring relevant code snippet and if there is an error in code snippet responsible annotation throw a custom exception. because i don't want to use try catch block inside my code snippet.but it will be implemented annotation class.(login)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389808/using-annotations-for-exception-handling

Comment: Nope its is not.i don't use any method and on top of it i don't declare any annotation. i wanna do the same thing without method.it was just a idea to implement seems like there is no way to do it.Thanks @aconkey for your time.