# How to wrap a method with try-catch by annotation?

Tags: java, spring, try-catch

If an exception should be ignored inside a method call, one would write eg the following:

```
public void addEntryIfPresent(String key, Dto dto) {
   try {
        Map<String, Object> row = database.queryForMap(key);
        dto.entry.put(row);
   } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {}
}
```

I'm trying to write eg a custom `spring` annotation that has the same effect, but could just be applied to the method header. That could look similar to the following:

```
@IgnoreException(EmptyResultDataAccessException.class) //this annotation does not exist
public void addEntryIfPresent(String key, Dto dto) {
   Map<String, Object> row = database.queryForMap(key);
   dto.entry.put(row);
}
```

How could such an annotation be created?

Comment: You can refer to this link, I find it useful. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389808/using-annotations-for-exception-handling)

Comment: You can use AOP, if I'm not mistaken, on what to do when an Exception is thrown. Just to give a thought: https://dzone.com/articles/handling-exceptions-using-springs-aop

Comment: Afaik one has to explicit define the package+classname in an `AOP pointcut` catcher. I'd rather like to create an annotation that can by applied to any method, thus is defined generic....

Comment: Just curious: what would your client code look like if you ignore exceptions such as this one? This could lead to increased complexity for callees when you're not sure if there is a result or not.

Comment: @membersound nope. the package and classname that needs to be put in the pointcut, is that of the annotation. I once wrote a small library containing all the configuration of aop. All I needed to do later on, was just add the annotation I wanted on the method I wanted it on, and to provide an implementation in case I chose not to use the default one I had provided in the library

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way of doing it with **AspectJ**.

First of all, define a method level annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface IgnoreRuntimeException{

}
```

Then, define an *around* aspect for the annotation.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class ExceptionHandlingAdvice {

    @Around("@annotation(com.yourpackage.IgnoreRuntimeException) && execution(* *(..))")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object returnObject = null;
        // do something before the invocation
        try {
            // invoke method
            returnObject = joinPoint.proceed();
            // do something with the returned object
            return returnObject;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do something with the exception
        }
    }

}
```

You can then apply the annotation on top of your methods to ignore exceptions.

```
@IgnoreRuntimeException
public void addEntryIfPresent(String key, Dto dto) {
    // ...
}
```

You can also check the parameters of the annotation using the api of `ProceedingJoinPoint` to ignore only the exceptions that you'd like to ignore.

Comment: Since database.queryForMap(key) throws EmptyResultDataAccessException which I assume is a checked exception, I don't think the code would compile.

Comment: @aka-one https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/EmptyResultDataAccessException.html

Comment: @aka-one if it was a checked exception, the `addEntryIfPresent` method from OPs example would not compile.

Comment: Ok, but what if in addEntryIfPresent body I call a method that throws an unchecked exception? I want to point out your code works only for unchecked exceptions.

Comment: Then the `addEntryIfPresent` in its current form would no longer compile.

Comment: It is possible to pass the classtype of the to be ignored exception as an argument to the annotation? Cause I want to ignore a specific exception on one method, and for the next method I'd might want to ignore a different exception. It would not be handy if I'd have to create a concrete annotation for each ignore-case.

Comment: @membersound This should help you with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275819/how-to-get-a-methods-annotation-value-from-a-proceedingjoinpoint