# Centralized Error Handler for Spring @TransactionalEventListener

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-async

Is there any way to specify centralized error handler for methods annotated with `@TransactionalEventListener`, since I want to direct certain exceptions to specific logger.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this approach with AspectJ: [How to wrap a method with try-catch by annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52924708/how-to-wrap-a-method-with-try-catch-by-annotation)

The solution is as follows:

1. Create a method level annotation
2. Create an aspect around that annotation
3. In the aspect, log whatever you desire in case of an exception occuring